# Adding elements to array via chained functions calls

Tags: javascript, arrays, rows, cells, chained

I have an array:

```
        var cells = [
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]
        ];
```

My javascript code parse this array and draw as a table.

Now i want add functions to simplify adding rows and cells to table, so i begin with this code:

```
Array.prototype.tsoAddRow = function () {
    this.push([]);
    return this[this.length-1];
};


Array.prototype.tsoAddCell = function (value) {
    this.push(value);
};

cells.tsoAddRow().tsoAddCell("123");
```

It works fine, result is `Array [ Array[1] ]` but i need more.

How i can improve this functions so i able use them ike this:

```
cells.tsoAddRow().tsoAddCell("1").tsoAddCell("2").tsoAddCell("3")
.tsoAddRow().tsoAddCell("4").tsoAddCell("5").tsoAddCell("6")
.tsoAddRow().tsoAddCell("7").tsoAddCell("8").tsoAddCell("9")
```

Or similar chained way. Tables can be much more complicated, for example, here another one:

```
        cells = [
            [
                "Lorem ipsum",
                "Lorem ipsum2",
                [
                    ["111", "222"]
                ]
            ],
            [
                "Lorem ipsum1",
                "Lorem ipsum12"
            ],
            [
                "Lorem ipsum2",
                "Lorem ipsum22"
            ],
```

**Update 1:**

Thank to @binariedMe i have solution, here alternative for array above, but with using only chained functions:

```
        cells
            .tsoAddRow()
                .tsoAddCell("Lorem ipsum")
                .tsoAddCell("Lorem ipsum")
                .tsoAddCell(
                    new Array().tsoAddRow()
                        .tsoAddCell("111")
                        .tsoAddCell("222")
                    )
            .tsoAddRow()
                .tsoAddCell("Lorem ipsum1")
                .tsoAddCell("Lorem ipsum12")
            .tsoAddRow()
                .tsoAddCell("Lorem ipsum2")
                .tsoAddCell("Lorem ipsum22");
```

Comment: pass the array as an argument and push to that array

Comment: _"Now i want add functions to simplify adding rows and cells to table"_ And therefor you're messing with the `Array` prototype? O.o

Comment: What is expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make this function for tsoAddCell

```
Array.prototype.tsoAddCell = function (value) {
  this.length && this[this.length-1].push(value); return this;
};
```

And make tsoAddRow function like this :

```
Array.prototype.tsoAddRow = function () {
  this.push([]);
  return this;
};
```

Explanation :

adding cell shall be done on the last row added but to chain everything we need to every time return the original array so that we can perform next task on it.
Hence you need to return this from each function.

Comment: Only thing you should remember is that you must add cell following to adding row and cells will be added to last row only as mentioned in question.

Comment: Added an explanation for the same @RobG :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.tsoAddCell = function (value) {
    var _this = this;
    value.forEach(function(i) {
        _this.push(i);
    })
};

cells.tsoAddRow().tsoAddCell([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the method chaining, like you describe in your request, you will need to return the current array also from the tsoAddCell method. So

```
Array.prototype.tsoAddCell = function (value) {
    this.push(value);
    return this;
};
```

But I doubt this will give you the flexibility you might expect, since it will only allow you to create nested arrays within the current array, not for example a new sibling row of the current row.

If you want more flexibility, you might use a combination of my answer and the one from Vasilij.

Or if you need even more flexibility, you should provide another method that allows to select the parent array of the current array. But then you would need to keep track of that parent array. Something like:

```
Array.prototype.tsoAddRow = function () {
    this.push([]);
    var row = this[this.length-1];
    row.parent = this;
    return row;
};

Array.prototype.parent = function() {
    return this.parent;
}
```

Then your request would become something like:

```
cells.tsoAddRow().tsoAddCell("1").tsoAddCell("2").tsoAddCell("3")
.parent().tsoAddRow().tsoAddCell("4").tsoAddCell("5").tsoAddCell("6")
.parent().tsoAddRow().tsoAddCell("7").tsoAddCell("8").tsoAddCell("9");
```

And then as an improvement you might add some logic to tsoAddRow to check for the parent himself, so you can avoid the explicit call to parent(). But that is of course only useful if you only have to construct a 2 dimensional array. In case you need more dimensions, you API will need to be extended.